# Using leftover Cuban bread

Tags: bread, dessert, breadcrumbs, bread-pudding

At the holidays, my office does a holiday party.  Last year we had Cuban food catered.  We are doing the same this year too.  Last year we had A LOT of Cuban bread left over.  I expect the same this year.

Since Cuban bread has a tendency to be a softer (less hearty) bread, if I used the leftovers to make bread pudding, would the bread simply dissolve into the dessert?

Comment: Questions like this don't do well on our site, as they are opinion based and lead to numerous, equally valid responses.

Comment: @moscafj, I edited the question so hopefully it's asking for a more science-based answer and not opinion.  That wasn't my intention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

You can [take advantage of the bread dissolving](https://recipeland.com/recipe/v/cuban-bread-pudding-51975), or you can [bake the pudding without a soaking period](https://icuban.com/food/pudin_de_pan.html) to get distinct cubes of bread.